# How to initialize a struct using a pointer

Tags: c

When I want to initialize all the components of a struct I do it in the `main` function like this:

This is the `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int data[1000];
    int oc;
} Table;
```

And this is how I initialize all the components to be 0 (the array and the int now are 0 with this).

```
int main() {
    Table x = {0};
```

Now I want to do exactly the same but using a function. I want to do something like this:

```
void initialize(Table *y) {
    y = {0};
}
```

I think it does not work because to initialize it I should do it when I declare it, so how can I initialize a struct using a function?

Comment: There is no point passing a `struct` to a function if you are going to treat it as a local variable and overwrite whatever was in it.

Comment: Yes it is a pointer I have just changed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `y` us a *pointer* so you must dereference it to assign the object itself.

Also you need to tell the compiler that the assignment is from a `Table` object, which is done with a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

All in all:

```
void initialize(Table *y){
    *y = (Table){0};
}
```

---

The compound literal creates `(Table){0}` creates a temporary `Table` structure object, with the initializer for the structure. Then this temporary structure object is assigned (copied to) the `Table` structure object that `y` points to.

It's somewhat similar to the following:

```
void initialize(Table *y){
    Table temp_struct_object = {0};  // Normal initialization
    *y = temp_struct_object;  // Normal assignment (copy of object)
}
```

Comment: And it is usually the most efficient way as well (assuming compiler optimizations enabled)\

Comment: This method is only to initialize structs or can it be used in arrays like this(It doesn´t work so how can I use that method to initialize whatever I want but not doing it in the declaration as the first example I have put?                                 
int main(){

int table[5];

table = table{0};

Comment: @Tenko Arrays can't be assigned to from the beginning, only copied to.

Comment: @Tenko It's possible to create array like that as well, for example `(int[5]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. But as mentioned it's not possible to assign to array.

Comment: ```                                                                                                                                       
 int main(){

int table[5];
int table2[5]={0};

table=table2;                                                                                                                      ```                                                                                                                                                   To assign to array you mean doing this? Why this can not be done as the structs?

Comment: @Tenko Correct, that's not possible. As for why you have to take that up with the creators of C... :)

Answer (score 6):

Just [memset](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html) it.

```
void initialize(Table *y) {
    memset(y, 0, sizeof *y);
}
```